# 2 Text boxes optional inserting in one or both

Tags: xcode, swift

I have two text fields to insert numbers, I am trying to find out how it could work out if the user is just inserting one value in one of the text fields or two. I tried to do it with if statements, but that does not work. Looks also like I have a mistake some where in the code I get the issue: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** I would be happy for some help - as you can see I am a beginner in swift coding. Thanks so Far!

```
@IBOutlet var budgetShow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var restShow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var daysShow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var dayssShow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var inputDays: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputBudget: UITextField!
@IBAction func findResult(sender: AnyObject) {

    var inputBudgetInt = inputBudget.text.toInt()

    var inputDaysInt = inputDays.text.toInt()

    var dailyRate = 85.50

    if inputDays != nil {

        var days = Double(inputBudgetInt!) / dailyRate

        var daysCosts = dailyRate * days

        var daysShow = Int(days)

        var costsShow = Int(daysCosts)

        dayssShow.text = "For \(costsShow) you can stay \(daysShow) Days."

    }

    if inputBudget != nil {    
        var budget = dailyRate / Double(inputBudgetInt!)

        var budgetShow = Int(budget)

        daysShow.text = "You need /(budgetShow)"
    }

    var daysBudget = Double(inputBudgetInt!) / Double(inputDaysInt!)
    var show = daysBudget - dailyRate
    var costs = Double(inputDaysInt!) * dailyRate
    var rest = Double(inputBudgetInt!) - costs
    var could = Double(inputBudgetInt!) / dailyRate
    var couldShow = Int(could)
    var restedShow = Int(rest)
    var costShow = Int(costs)
    var dayShow = Int(inputDaysInt!)

    if show > 0  {         
        budgetShow.text = "For \(dayShow) Days you need \(costShow) €"
        restShow.text = "Rest Budget after \(dayShow) Days is \(restedShow) €"
        daysShow.text = "With your budget you could stay up to \(couldShow) days" 
    } else {   
        budgetShow.text = "Change your budget or days"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle optionals safely is `if let`, like follows:

```
if let inputBudgetInt = inputBudgetInt {
  // safely use it without need for "!" or "?"
  var days = Double(inputBudgetInt) / dailyRate
}
```

This basically means "if this optional has a value, unwrap it and use it here".

I like to keep the name the same personally, you can use a different name if you want.

Another way is using "?", especially good for chaining. If you have a reference to a cell for example:

```
cell.textField?.text = "Foo"
```

If `textField` (optional) has no value, this line silently does nothing.

You should avoid "!" as much as possible as it can easily cause a crash. Only if you are 100% sure it has a value should you risk it. As a beginner I would stick to `if let` to make sure your optionals have values.

Comment: thanks for your help, but as you can see at my last if statement - when i get both fields from the user fielded out, the answers should be different, how can I fix that?